# How to display google Ads using Adrotator asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How to display google Ads using Adrotator .... new ads every times page refreshes ?

Answer (score 1):

The `AdRotator` is show a sequency of ad images.

The google ads is a self dynamic show of advertize the google totally control and googles show what advertize he think that is appropriate to your page, base on the keywords and words that google found on your page.

So they can not mix together, just place your google ads javascript code to your page and thats all. The only think that you can rotate is between google ads and other ads, and this can not be done using the AdRotator